# Parse multiline logs as a single event in Fluentd

Tags: openshift, fluentd, efk

We have EFK implemented on Openshift Container Platform version 4.3.

Issue:
Multiline logs such as Java Stack trace, SQL queries are not getting parsed as a single event in Fluentd and because of this we are getting multiple entries in Kibana.
We need to parse multiline logs as a single event, so that we get a single entry in Kibana for an exception or SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy:** switch application logging format to json.

**Hard:** https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline.
Usually `format_firstline` and `format1` is enough - everything else is appended until the next `format_firstline` match.